# Exception accessing databases in embedded mono

Tags: c, mono

I've written a program in C that uses Embedded Mono calls to my C# library. 
I've got it working, but am having a problem with making SQL calls across my network.

Running normally, I get the following exception when I try to connect to the database:

> System.ArgumentException: Value does not fall within the expected
>   range.\r\n  at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.SetSocketOption 
>   (System.Net.Sockets.SocketOptionLevel optionLevel,
>   System.Net.Sockets.SocketOptionName optionName, System.Int32
>   optionValue)  [0x00061] in <5071a6e4a4564e19a2eda0f53e42f9bd>:0 \r\n 
>   at Mono.Data.Tds.Protocol.TdsComm..ctor (System.String dataSource, 
>   System.Int32 port, System.Int32 packetSize, System.Int32 timeout,
>   Mono.Data.Tds.Protocol.TdsVersion tdsVersion)

What is strange, is that when I run this in **gdb** (attempting to get a handle on what values are being passed, etc), everything works fine, and my database call succeeds.

Does anyone have any ideas?

I'm running in Windows 7, and my C code is compiled using gcc from minGW:

gcc test.c -mms-bitfields -ID:/Mono/include/mono-2.0 -LD:/Mono/lib -lmono-2.0 -mms-bitfields -lws2_32 -lpsapi -lole32 -lwinmm -loleaut32 -ladvapi32 -lversion

Update:
Using the following connection string, it now works 2 times out of 10:
Server=192.168.1.54;Database=MyDb;User Id=my_user;Password=mypwd123;Integrated Security=False

```
#include <mono/jit/jit.h>  
#include <mono/metadata/object.h>  
#include <mono/metadata/environment.h>  
#include <mono/metadata/assembly.h>  
#include <mono/metadata/debug-helpers.h>  
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>

static MonoMethod *getMethod(char* methodName) 
{ 
        static MonoImage *img; 

        if(img == NULL) 
        { 
                MonoDomain *domain = mono_jit_init("my.dll"); 

                if(domain == NULL) 
                { 
                        return NULL; 
                } 

                MonoAssembly *assembly = mono_domain_assembly_open(domain, "my.dll"); 

                if(assembly == NULL) 
                { 
                        return NULL; 
                } 

                img = mono_assembly_get_image(assembly); 

                if(img == NULL) 
                { 
                        return NULL; 
                } 
        } 

        MonoMethodDesc *desc = mono_method_desc_new(methodName, true); 

        if(desc == NULL) 
                return NULL; 

    return mono_method_desc_search_in_image(desc, img); 
} 

int main(void) 
{ 
        MonoMethod *method = getMethod("MyNs.MyClass:MyFunc(string,string)"); 

        if(method == NULL) 
        { 
                puts("Method was null"); 
                return 1; 
        } 

        MonoObject* ex = NULL; 
        MonoObject *res = mono_runtime_invoke(method, NULL, NULL, &ex); 

        if(ex != NULL) 
        { 
                char *s = mono_string_to_utf8(mono_object_to_string(ex, NULL)); 
                puts(s); 
                return 2; 
        } 

        if(res == NULL) 
        { 
                puts("No result"); 
                return 3; 
        } 

        char *rv = mono_string_to_utf8(mono_object_to_string(res, NULL)); 
        puts(rv); 
        return 0; 
}
```

C# code:

```
public static string MyFunc(string connectionString, string query)
        {
            using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
            {
                SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(query, connection);
                connection.Open();
                using (SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader())
                {
                    while (reader.Read())
                        return reader.GetString(0);
                }
            }

            return "No data found";
        }
```

Comment: add the c# code also

Comment: The c# code opens a SQL connection, calls a stored procedure, and returns a value. Works fine running in .Net, Core CLR and Mono, just blows up when called via embedded mono, and when not in the debugger.

Comment: The problem here is the exception is arisen in the managed side, at some point it does an TCP connection with something (seems to be the SQL connection) and a parameter passed to the socket is incorrect. It seems you're using the Mono.Data.Tds provider which is no longer mantained and deprecated, I suspect the problem comes from there. Are you using SQL Server or Sybase? If it's SQL server if you use System.Data.SqlClient provider it probably will work as expected.

Comment: I haven't explicitly used Mono.Data.Tds, the C# code is all written against Microsoft libraries, I'm using System.Data and System.Data.SqlClient

Comment: Gosh, you're right, SqlClient uses Tds as the underlying connector... the documentation is awful on mono... What version of mono do you have installed?

Comment: 4.6.2.16 - latest download as of last week

Comment: Can you post from the C# code the relevant lines to the connection creation? Seeing the connection string (obviously hidding server/password) can shed some light to your problem.

Comment: Data Source=MyServer.MyDomain.com;Database=MyDb;User Id=app_user;Password=somePassword123;Application Name=MyApp;Connect Timeout=150;

Comment: Just as a long shot, try to use IP address instead of domain name.

Comment: More weird behaviour - I added the following to my C code to force a call out to the debugger just before the offending call: __asm__("int3");

Comment: The DB call succeeds in this case too - attaching a Visual Studio 2015 debugger

Comment: Same behaviour using the IP address too - fails as long as I don't have a debugger attached

Comment: Basically, it doesn't seem to matter what debugger I have attached, as long as there is one

Comment: That's really odd. Is the assembly compiled for debug or for release? And x64 or x86? Also, asking on the mono mailing list will give you a better chance to get to someone which had this problem.

Comment: It's compiled for release, x86. I've tried all variations, x86, x64, release and debug, all have the same behaviour. I've asked on the mailing list, it's filled with spam, and very few replies. :-( - http://mono.1490590.n4.nabble.com/Debugging-Embedded-Mono-in-Python-C-extension-td4669812.html

Comment: To be clear, no-one has replied to my thread of 25-Jan-2017 - the thread only has 8 views, most of those mine.

Comment: WIth an altered command line it now works 2 or 3 times out of ten, but when it fails, same error. I've also attached the C# code.